# How to use [ngClass] with simple condition and ternary condition?

Tags: css, angular

I have a series of a tags that represent steps. As shown here, if step one is the current step, apply the step-active class.

```
<a (click)="goStep2" [ngClass]="{'step-active': currentStep === 1 }">
 Step 1
</a>
```

Now, I'd like also to add another condition which related to the contain of the page. Let's user has responded to all the required questions. I'd like to highlight the step by green if the step is valid, otherwise by red.

```
<a (click)="goStep2" [ngClass]="{'step-active': currentStep === 1,
    isValid ? 'valid-state' : 'invalid-state' }">
 Step 1
</a>
```

I'm getting an error about missing `:`. How to apply this 2 conditions given that the first one is just a simple condition while the second is a ternary one.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

```html
<a (click)="goStep2" [ngClass]="{'step-active': currentStep === 1,
    'valid-state' : isValid, 'invalid-state': !isValid }">
 Step 1
</a>
```